# Sequence Limit: $\sin(n^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that this sequence does not converge, using  the definition?

> $$W_n = \sin(n^3)$$

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I tried to do a proof by reduction to the absurd but without result.

Comment: There is no limit, the sequence do not converge to anywhere.

Comment: I know that it does not converge but i don't know how to prove it.

Comment: We say that a sequence _diverges_ if it goes to plus or minus infinity. If a sequence do not converge we say that the _limit do not exist_ I think someone will answer this but as a felling you could try to (1) show that two different sub-sequences converge to different values.

Comment: I couldn't find any... The n^3 bother me.

Comment: (+1) In hope that someone answer it. Seems a very technical prove

Comment: @RafaelWagner I'm pretty sure that's not true. Any sequence that does not converge is said to diverge, even if it doesn't go to plus or minus infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/254b-notes-1-equidistribution-of-polynomial-sequences-in-torii/

As a special case of Corollary 6, we have

> Let $P(n)=a_s n^s + \cdots + a_0$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. If $a_s$ is irrational, then $P(n)$ mod $1$ is equidistributed.

With $P(n)=\frac1{2\pi} n^3$, we have $P(n)$ mod $1$ is equidistributed. Thus, $n^3$ mod $2\pi$ is equidistributed. Then it follows that $\sin n^3$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.